# 'importfromweb' addon to scratch data from StockX

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have added 'importfromweb' addon to scratch data from StockX. Unfortunately I faced with some issues and I don't really know how to solve this issue. If you look at the picture, you may see two links from StockX website with sneakers. You may also see Xpath copied from those two links insdicating to the price of the shoe above. Unfortunately the first shows an Error and I dont know why.
The arguments of the function are placed correcty
[image: Here is the Image]

Links: https://stockx.com/air-jordan-36-flipped-infrared-23
https://stockx.com/air-jordan-36-low-black-multi-color

I have tried to search the reasons from the internet but I did not find anything about how to solve this problem

Comment: Please include the simplest formulas we can copy and paste ourselves to replicate the issue as well as the desired output verses the actual one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in function IMPORTHTML instead.